# How can I install apache, mysql, php on ubuntu desktop

Tags: system-installation

I just installed Ubuntu 13.10 desktop, I would like to know can I install Apache, MySQL and PHP on Ubuntu desktop version or do I need to install on the Ubuntu server version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Ubuntu. You can install nearly anything nearly anywhere. The anwser is yes.

EDIT: To install, look [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @amc: What doesn't it answer? The question was "can I install Apache, etc. in desktop ubuntu?". The answer is yes.

Comment: If users on this site took such a literal view, every answer to the questions posed here would be "yes" or "no".  Please provide a detailed answer that explains *HOW* to actually install [in this case] apache, mysql, php.

Comment: *facepalm* Of course. Working on it.

Comment: no worries -- I would check for duplicate answers already written. there has to be one (or more) for this...installing LAMP stack is a common task!

Comment: Thanks for the information and helping, I am pretty new for Ubuntu. Can you please provide the link for the instruction to install them, thanks again,  Regards, Inung

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP

Comment: Thanks for the information and help, Do I need use command line to install or there is a way from Graphic interface? Thanks again for helping and Information, Regards, Inung

Comment: I recommend Synaptic, but there are others I don't know the names of.